# problem on iOS, not look good at the bottom because of the indicator how to fix?

Tags: react-native, expo

how can I fix this ? my modal or every screen is looking like this because of the indicator at the bottom. I dont want to set on every screen now a margin or padding its time consuming. is there a better solution to fix this ?

code:

```
    <BottomSheetModal
      ref={ref}         
      index={1}
      snapPoints={snapPoints}
      keyboardBehavior='interactive'
      handleIndicatorStyle={[s.handleStyle, s.handleColorWhite]}
      backdropComponent={BottomSheetBackdrop}
    >
        <View style={s.centered}>
          <Text style={s.title}>testtset</Text>
          <Text style={s.subtitle}>testtest</Text>
          <Text style={s.stepText}>{`Schritt ${step}/3`}</Text>
        </View>
 
       
                <Text style={[s.text, s.bold]}>Nur Buchstaben & Zahlen!</Text>
                <View style={s.content}>
                  <View style={s.inputContainer}>
                    <Input
                      placeholder='Name'
                      value={name}
                      onChangeText={handleChangeName}
                      style={[InputStyles.full_icon, Platform.OS === 'ios' && s.inputPaddingV]}
                      icon={<Ionicons name="md-newspaper-outline" size={24} style={s.icon} color="#333" />}
                      isBottomSheet={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? true : false}
                    />
                  </View>
                  <View style={s.containerInner}>
                    <Pressable onPress={handleChangeStage} style={[ButtonStyles.full]}>
                      <Text style={s.btnText}>Weiter zu 2</Text>
                    </Pressable>
                  </View>
                </View>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add margin in the Stack Screen:

```
<Stack.Screen name="YourScreenName" component={YourComponent} options={{
   cardStyle:{
          marginBottom: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 24 : 0
        }
  }} />
```

or directly in the Stack Navigator:

```
<Stack.Navigator
   initialRouteName={routeName}
   screenOptions={{
        cardStyle:{
          marginBottom: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 24 : 0
        }
      }}>
```